# How to make animation like i attach a video

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, bottom-sheet

I want this type of bottom menu in flutter. I scroll anywhere on screen bottom menu will appear. And when I scroll vertically down it will disappear and on slide up it will appear

[image: I want this type of bottom menu in flutter. I scroll anywhere on screen bottom menu will appear. And when I scroll vertically down it will disappear and on slide up it will appear]

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use [showModalBottomSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html) for this type of widgets.

Sample code:

```
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('showModalBottomSheet'),
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet<void>(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Container(
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.amber,
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const Text('Modal BottomSheet'),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        child: const Text('Close BottomSheet'),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here are the good package which is useful to get pages as you want:
[modal_bottom_sheet](https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet)

How you can use it:

```
showMaterialModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => Container(),
)
```

For more attributes, you can visit [documentation here](https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet#material-modal-bottomsheet)

Example Link : [Modal Bottom Sheet](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/modal-bottom-sheet-in-flutter-dae05debbed2)

Comment: this is not what i need. menu will appear on sliding the finger on the screen not on button press

Comment: That will be part of your logic. You can check this example : https://medium.com/@adityadroid/60-days-of-flutter-day-6-7-implementing-a-slideable-widget-using-bottomsheet-in-flutter-c320dc106f2b